# Why the result of output of randomize is repeating the same?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want each of iteration display different value of random array. Why my output only display the same random value for each iteration and n_particles?

```py
import random as rd
import numpy as np 

n_iterations = int(input("Inform the number of iterations: "))
n_particles = int(input("Inform the number of particles: "))

# a1,a2,a3=100

a3=rd.randint(0,1)
a2=rd.randint(0,50)
a1=100-a2-a3

particle_position_vector =  np.array([np.array([a1, a2, a3]) for _ in range(n_particles)])

iteration = 0
while iteration < n_iterations:
    print("iteration : ", iteration)
    for i in range(n_particles):
        print(particle_position_vector[i])
```

I expect the output for a1, a2, a3 should be randomize different value when looping instead of same randomize value..

The output below is what I have get not as my expected output be like...

```
iteration :  0
[ 97  2  1]  
[ 97  2  1]  
iteration :  1
[ 97  2  1]  
[ 97  2  1]
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [minimal working example](/help/mcve). Right now there are a number of names not defined (e.g. `rd`, `np`). Contentwise, it seems like you generate your random numbers outside of the loop. Also, you may want to use `numpy.random` instead of `random` as you seems to be doing.

Comment: i've tried to simplify my coding.. hopefully it will be more understandable

Answer (score 3):

Because you are fixing the result of a RNG to a variable.

```
a3=rd.randint(0,1)
a2=rd.randint(0,50)
a1=100-a2-a3
```

Is not within a loop and will not generate new values everytime the for loop iterates, instead, `a3, a2, a1` will have constant values generated randomly once.
If you want to have `a3, a2, a1` be random values for each iteration in your while loop, then you need to define them within your loop.

```
iteration = 0
while iteration < n_iterations:
   a3=rd.randint(0,1)
   a2=rd.randint(0,50)
   a1=100-a2-a3
   particle_position_vector =  np.array([np.array([rd.randint(0,2), rd.randint(0,2), a1, a2, a3]) for _ in range(n_particles)])
    print("iteration : ", iteration)
    for i in range(n_particles):

        fitness_cadidate = fitness_function(particle_position_vector[i])
        print(-(fitness_cadidate), ' ', particle_position_vector[i], ' ')
```

#### Edit: OP said code isn't working

Here you can see what I tried, and I'll copy/paste exactly the output from command line.

```
import random as rd
import numpy as np 
n_particles = 10
iteration = 5
n_iterations = 10
while iteration < n_iterations:
   a3=rd.randint(0,1)
   a2=rd.randint(0,50)
   a1=100-a2-a3
   particle_position_vector =  np.array([np.array([rd.randint(0,2), rd.randint(0,2), a1, a2, a3]) for _ in range(n_particles)])
   print(a3)
   print(a2)
   print(a1)
   print(particle_position_vector)
   iteration += 1
```

Output:

```
1
30
69
[[ 2  2 69 30  1]
 [ 2  0 69 30  1]
 [ 0  2 69 30  1]
 [ 1  1 69 30  1]
 [ 1  0 69 30  1]
 [ 0  0 69 30  1]
 [ 2  0 69 30  1]
 [ 1  0 69 30  1]
 [ 2  1 69 30  1]
 [ 1  1 69 30  1]]
0
50
50
[[ 1  2 50 50  0]
 [ 0  2 50 50  0]
 [ 2  2 50 50  0]
 [ 1  0 50 50  0]
 [ 0  1 50 50  0]
 [ 2  0 50 50  0]
 [ 0  0 50 50  0]
 [ 0  2 50 50  0]
 [ 1  1 50 50  0]
 [ 1  1 50 50  0]]
1
23
76
[[ 2  0 76 23  1]
 [ 2  0 76 23  1]
 [ 1  1 76 23  1]
 [ 2  0 76 23  1]
 [ 2  1 76 23  1]
 [ 2  0 76 23  1]
 [ 1  0 76 23  1]
 [ 1  2 76 23  1]
 [ 2  2 76 23  1]
 [ 0  1 76 23  1]]
1
7
92
[[ 2  1 92  7  1]
 [ 0  0 92  7  1]
 [ 2  2 92  7  1]
 [ 1  1 92  7  1]
 [ 1  2 92  7  1]
 [ 1  1 92  7  1]
 [ 0  2 92  7  1]
 [ 0  2 92  7  1]
 [ 1  0 92  7  1]
 [ 2  0 92  7  1]]
1
2
97
[[ 2  2 97  2  1]
 [ 1  0 97  2  1]
 [ 1  2 97  2  1]
 [ 0  2 97  2  1]
 [ 1  2 97  2  1]
 [ 2  2 97  2  1]
 [ 2  1 97  2  1]
 [ 2  1 97  2  1]
 [ 1  1 97  2  1]
 [ 2  2 97  2  1]]
```

As you can see, for each iteration, `a1`,`a2`, and `a3` have different random values assigned.

Comment: how can I put that variable into loops? I've tried to put that into loop but it return the same...

Comment: i've tried your code.. the result remain the same as before

Comment: alright.. i can see your code is randomize between iteration and sorry i forgot to mention that I need the value are also randomized between n_particles :'))

Comment: Thank you Celius.. I've solved my problem. I just put the code in for i in range (n_particles): and it return my expected output

Comment: I'm glad we could work it out together! The most important thing however is how you use random generators inside or outside loops, the rest is pretty much architerctural.